# Discord.js can i execute a file inside of another file

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have My Main Index.js File, Inside That, I have This Code  (Imagine Input is !help)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
client.on("error", console.error);
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('ProBot is online!');
});
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.guild === null) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith("!")){
        const prefix = "!";
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        if (command.length === 0) return;
        let cmd = client.commands.get(command);
        if (!cmd) return message.reply(`\`${prefix + command}\` doesn't exist!`);
        cmd.execute(message, args);
    }
};
```

Then That Opens the file **help.js**, example being

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: "!help Command",
    execute(message, args){
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_GUILD")){  //Regular Output
            message.react('❤️')
            const help2Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ffd6d6')
            .setTitle('!Help\n')
            .setDescription('Check Your Private Messages For More Information')
            message.channel.send(help2Embed)
            const h11elpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ffd6d6')
            .setTitle('!Help\n')
            .setDescription('This Bot Has Lots Of Special Features\n \n \nGeneral Commands Are;\n \n!blacklist   = Shows The BlackListed Words\n!safe          = Disables The Filter For That Message\n!server      = Displays Server Name, Total Members And Amount On/Offline')
            message.author.send(h11elpEmbed)
            return;
        }
}}
```

Question Is, If it was Changed To be a !warn @member [low, med, high] [reason] - Could The Index Take it to a warn.js file, then from there depending on if args[2] is low, med, high open and execute a new file? to run a different code for each.[or if there is an easier way I have overlooked]

Comment: you can just create a new file, that you can name however you want, according to the schema you already have. Inside that file you can then handle whatever parameters you wish to use with that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the question and get an answer.

a really helpful comment from @worthy Alpaca (all credit to them)
`you can just create a new file, that you can name however you want, according to the schema you already have. Inside that file you can then handle whatever parameters you wish to use with that command`